# Dado selecionado da tag <option> para passar ao Model C# - MVC

Tags: c#, html, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com HTML e C# nos padrões MVC, e em um dos menus necessito colocar uma lista de opções em qual o usuário irá selecionar o que quer, esses dados são provenientes do banco de dados, então o que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

Criei um Model e lá criei uma lista.

```
public class NotasFiscaisModel
    {
        public virtual string usuarioLogado { get; set; }
        public virtual string dataUltimoLogin { get; set; }
        public virtual string unidadeInicio { get; set; }
        public virtual string unidadeFim { get; set; }
        public virtual string dataInicial { get; set; }
        public virtual string dataFinal { get; set; }
        public virtual string nome { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<NotasFiscaisModel> autorizados { get; set; }
    }
```

Com isso, faço um select para popular minha lista de autorizados

```
     foreach (DataRow linha in autoriz.RetornaAutorizados(LoginController._login.empresa).Rows)
  {
     NotasFiscaisModel nota = new NotasFiscaisModel();
     nota.nome = linha["nome"].ToString();
     _notas.autorizados.Add(nota);
  }
```

Dentro do HTML, possuo um trecho que lista as opções via tag option:

```
    <td>
      <div class="col-xs-2" style="width:190px">
           <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option>Todos</option>
              @foreach (var obj in Model.autorizados)
              {
              <option>@obj.nome</option>
              }
              </select>
         </div>
     </div>
</td>
```

Isso funciona, como mostra o que está acontecendo no print abaixo (nao liguem pros valores, é base de teste kkk):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu gostaria de pegar qual o usuário selecionou, retornando para meu Model, fazendo o Controller ter acesso a esse conteúdo e poder fazer mais operações, existe uma maneira?

Comment: Defina um name para seu select               
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1">
Com isso você consegue pegar o valor por meio de uma propriedade do objeto que colocar no parâmetro da action pra onde enviar o form, ou pelo Request, assim: Request.Form["sel1"]).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378338/how-to-get-selected-value-of-a-html-select-with-asp-net

Comment: @MarceloVieira funcionou, muito obrigado! =)

Comment: @MarceloVieira seria interessante  você adicionar a resposta, assim o Bruno consegue dar resposta aceita e a solução fica para a comunidade ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defina um name para seu select

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1">
```

Com isso você consegue pegar o valor por meio de uma propriedade do objeto que colocar no parâmetro da action pra onde enviar o form, ou pelo Request, assim:

```
Request.Form["sel1"])
```

Veja mais em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378338/how-to-get-selected-value-of-a-html-select-with-asp-net